# VB->Option strict and LINQ result

Tags: vb.net, linq, option-strict

I was recently introduced to LINQ and got a sample how to search for error messages after executing a query against a database. The code looks like this:

```
        Dim errors As Object = From e In execution.Messages _
        Where e.MessageType = 120 Or e.MessageType = 110
        Select e.Message

        If errors IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each m As OperationMessage In errors
                LogToError("ExecutePackage->Error message: " & m.Message)
                sbError.AppendLine(m.Message)
            Next
        End If
```

Now, when I use **Option strict ON** I get an error on the "errors" object on this line:

```
For Each m As OperationMessage In errors
```

This is natural for me. So, I tried to change the code to this:

```
For Each m As OperationMessage In CType(errors, OperationMessageCollection)
```

Now, when I run it I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.OperationMessage,System.String]' to type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.OperationMessageCollection'.
```

So, it seems to me that converting a LINQ query to another type at runtime does not work? What is the proper way of doing this and keeping **Option strict ON**?

Comment: Use Option Infer On and delete `As Object`.

Comment: Use `Dim errors As IEnumerable(Of OperationMessage)` instead of `Object` or simply `Dim errors` without any type (same as `var` in C#) (**Edit** + `Option Infer` as mentioned by Hans  Passant).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I get this error if I use the enumerable:

 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.OperationMessage,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.OperationMessage]'.